# How to pass get parameter to ngResource in angularJ

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't find a way to pass a simple id parameter to the resource I have created.

the service is:

```js
angular.
  module('shared.testUser').
  factory('TestUser', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/:id', {id:'@userid'});
    }
  ]);
```

The component and controller which uses it is:

```js
angular.
  module('logIn').
  component('logIn', {
   templateUrl: 'log-in/log-in.template.html',
 controller: ['TestUser', function LogInController(TestUser) {
  self = this;
       self.testUserSet = TestUser.query();
       self.oneUser = TestUser.get({userid:3});
       self.testVar = 20;
   }]
  });
```

Currently I get an error when I try to run this on the `self.oneuser` line.

> Error: $resource:badcfg
>   Response does not match configured parameter
>   Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers)

I have tried many ways to represent this line, but no matter what i do it fails

Comment: Is the error on the TestUser.query() line or the next one?
Basically, query() expects an array whereas get expects an object

Comment: Its on the get line

Comment: I have tried everything mentioned so far, including re-writing and simplifying to a single file, but the fundamental difference is that I am using (a) a component and (b) an external HTTP call ,not a local call to a json file.  I don't know if these are causing the error, but the code will not allow me to search for a single ID. The current error I'm getting is:

Comment: angular.min.js:118 TypeError: V is not a function
    at http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular-resource.min.js:13:165
    at q (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular.min.js:7:449)
    at Object.setUrlParams (http://localhost:8888/IIIRef/app/shared/angular-resource.min.js:13:50)
    at Function.l.(anonymous function) [as get]

Answer (score 0):

Use the same identifiers from the $resource function definition.

Because you have this:

```
return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/testusers/:id', {id:'@userid'});
```

Your component while sending the param should bind as {id: 1234}.

Note that I changed the identifier from userid to id (which is how you identify your own parameters which you defined in $resource.  You don't have to wrestle with Angular or yourself to get it working, just get the conventions right).

There is no such thing as passing a body in get request *with respect to this syntax*.  The params as defined in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource and explained in the example just below the syntax definition/usage are meant as binding to the placeholders *you created* in $resource.  *Do not confuse $http and $resource*.

[My working plunk for your reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/jFbek1GHkP5pfYKvFpSJ?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Mahesh,  I'm sorry but I still don't understand and my code still doesn't work even when I change the name of the parameter to id.  I don't understand how your code runs.  The error I now have is: TypeError: V is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `$resource` defines the defaults for the parameters:

```
app.factory('TestUser', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('testusers.json/:id', {id:'default'});
    }
]);
```

To override the default in a GET action, use the parameter name:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, TestUser) {

    var vm=$scope;

    vm.testUserSet = TestUser.query();
    vm.oneUser = TestUser.get({id:3});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/a6WKUVWJFoDR3Ia3Ay3U?p=preview)